# Do changes made within one transaction "see" each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions

Suppose I do the following set of SQL queries (pseudocode) in a table with only one column `CITY`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES( 'COOLCITY' );
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ALL;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

is the `SELECT` guaranteed to return `COOLCITY`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The `INSERT` operation would take an `X` lock out on at least the newly added row. This won't get released until the end of the transaction thus preventing a concurrent transaction from deleting or updating this row.

A transaction is not blocked by its own locks so the `SELECT` would return COOLCITY.